# yiiGridView problem

Tags: php, gridview, grid, yii

Hallo mench.

I have an yiiGridView issue witch I don't know how to make right.

So, I have CGridView nicely initialized and I need the $(tableId).yiiGridView.update(tableId, settings), to reload my datagrid with new data.

Can anyone (PLEASE!) post some example how to achive this.

If needed, I can send my code as well, so anyone who can resolve this issue can see in the better where I'm making mistakes.

Thanks in advance(d).

Comment: and it's kinda urgent as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update your grid with javascript handler use next code

```
jQuery.fn.yiigridview.update('yourGridId');
```

You can find a lot of information in file

```
jquery.yiigridview.js

  /**
     * Performs an AJAX-based update of the grid view contents.
     * @param id string the ID of the grid view container
     * @param options map the AJAX request options (see jQuery.ajax API manual). By default,
     * the URL to be requested is the one that generates the current content of the grid view.
     */
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update = function(id, options)
```